# Laravel 5.2 Change public folder to public_html on shared server

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have uploaded my project to godaddy and moved public folder content to `public_html`. Project is working fine but Intervention image is unable to write in public path as it is not there. Below is the message:

```
Can't write image data to path (/home/username/public/uploads/...
```

So obviously `public_path()` is wrong, its still pointing `public`. But it should be `public_html` now.
So my question is how can I change this to `public_html` in Laravel 5.2?

Comment: this question is already answered with same topic

Comment: Consider symlinking `public` to `public_html`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in index.php:

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

// set the public path to this directory
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
});
```